# Sentiment Intensity Analyzer

Tags: python, list, nltk, data-science

I am getting 4 values for each row in sid.polarity_scores(row) as i want. But for each row i want 1st value of each row to go to 1st empty list formed respectively and 2nd value of each row to go to 2nd empty list formed , like that for 3rd and 4th also. but my all 4 values for each row goes to all 4 empty list formed .

```
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sentiment_pos=[]
sentiment_neg=[]
sentiment_neu=[]
sentiment_com=[]
for row in X_train["essay"]:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(row)
    for k in ss:
        sentiment_pos.append(sid.polarity_scores)
        sentiment_neg.append(sid.polarity_scores)
        sentiment_neu.append(sid.polarity_scores)
        sentiment_com.append(sid.polarity_scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their [docs](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sentiment.html#nltk.sentiment.vader.SentimentIntensityAnalyzer.polarity_scores), looks like it returns a dictionary of the 4 values, so you can just append to lists like this:

```
for row in X_train["essay"]:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(row)
    sentiment_pos.append(ss['pos'])
    sentiment_neg.append(ss['neg'])
    sentiment_neu.append(ss['neu'])
    sentiment_com.append(ss['compound'])
```

Comment: Getting the same out put like before even after using your code @Ricky.

Comment: Then I guess I did not understand your question. What is the output you got and what is your expected output?

Comment: There are 50k data points in X_train . after applying the code its Output should be Print(len(sentiment_pos))  =   50k . but its output is coming 200k . That means "pos" , "neg" , "neu" and "compound" all 4 values are going to each sentiment_pos , sentiment_neg ....... for every iteration . I want "pos" value to go to sentiment_pos  , "neg" value to go to sentiment_neg ..... like that for every iteration .   @Ricky

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? note that I got rid of `for k in ss`

Comment: Yes , you are right brother . its was my mistake , By mistake i created a nested loop . Its working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Np. Make sure to mark it as answered if it answered your question.